# How to create database using laravel auto generate?

Tags: laravel, generate

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table
```

This code does not generate a table on phpmyadmin.

What code should I use?

Comment: this would generate php code describing the table in `database>migrations`, to build that table run this `php artisan migrate`, and you should check the docs

Comment: I want to know what command line I use to create a table automatically!

Comment: There is no such command

Comment: But what is the best way to create a class or new class to make a table?